# How to fill the star rating survey multiple questions and capture the values?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 questions and I have built the star ratings with dynamic coloring (less than 3 color gold else green). But when I click for question 1 and then go to question 2 and click the stars there, then Q1 stars are getting reset. How to fix this? And also on Submit click I need to identify the filled stars against each question response.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

    * {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    body {
        font-family: SamsungOne, Arial;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #000;
    }
    header {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 19px 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    header img {
        width: 125px;
    }
    .error {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .text-wrapper {
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    input[type=text],
    select {
        height: 60px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
        outline: none;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    select:focus::-ms-value {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
    }
    select:-moz-focusring {
        color: transparent;
        text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
    }
    option:not(:checked) {
        color: #000;
    }
    .container {
        max-width: 1440px;
    }
    .main-container {
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 60px auto 50px auto;
    }
    .disclaimer-wrapper {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .form-elm-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .form-elm-input {
        flex-grow: 1;
        position: relative;
    }
    .submit-container {
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .styled-btn {
        font-family: SamsungOne, Arial;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 0 60px;
        height: 65px;
        border-radius: 33px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border: none;
        outline: none !important;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .btn-container {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .btn-container a, .btn-container button {
        margin: 0px 10px 10px;
    }
    .btn {
        font-family: SamsungOne, Arial;
        padding: 10px 40px;
        border-radius: 999px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        min-width: 110px;
        outline: none !important;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .btn-container a:hover, .btn-container button:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .btn-text {
        border-color: transparent;
        background-color: transparent;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        min-width: unset;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    #link {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    #facebook-btn {
        padding: 0 30px;
        line-height: 55px;
        margin: 0 0 40px 0;
        font-size: 15px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background-color: #1428A0;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #facebook-btn img{
        height: 32px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .label-left .form-elm-headline {
        align-self: center;
        margin-right: 30px;
        min-width: 140px;
        max-width: 140px;
    }
    .label-left .form-elm-headline.top-align {
        align-self: flex-start;
    }
    .label-top .form-elm-headline {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .form-elm-rc {
        max-width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .label-left .form-elm-rc {
        align-self: center;
    }
    .form-elm-rc label {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0 50px 0 0;
    }
    .captcha-wrapper {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .disclaimer-wrapper small{
        display: block;
    }
    .readmore {
        height: 57px;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
    }
    .readmore.active {
        height: auto;
    }
    a.readmoreBtn {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #00b3e3;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .readmoreBtn .readmoreText {
        display: block;
    }
    .readmoreBtn .readlessText {
        display: none;
    }
    .readmoreBtn.active .readmoreText{
        display: none;
    }
    .readmoreBtn.active .readlessText {
        display: block;
    }
    .req-star {
        color: #00b3e3;
        font-family: SamsungOne, Arial;
        margin-left: 2px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    /* Typografi setup */
    h3 {
        font-family: SamsungSharpSansBd, Arial;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 32px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    h4 {
        font-family: SamsungOne, Arial;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    p {
        font-family: SamsungOne, Arial;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    small {
        font-family: SamsungOne, Arial;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
    label.form-elm-headline {
        font-family: SamsungSharpSansBd, Arial;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 22px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .parsley-errors {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-size: 12px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: -20px;
    }
    /* Custom input fields*/
    .custom-input-container {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .custom-input-container.vertical {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .custom-input-container.vertical:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .custom-input-container input {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* Radio */
    .custom-radio {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border:1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .custom-radio:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #fff;
        top: 4px;
        left: 4px;
    }
    .custom-input-container input:checked ~ .custom-radio:after {
        background-color: #000;
    }

    /* Checkbox */
    .custom-checkbox {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border:1px solid #000;
    }
    .custom-checkbox:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        left: 9px;
        top: 4px;
        width: 10px;
        height: 15px;
        border: solid #000;
        border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    .custom-input-container input:checked ~ .custom-checkbox:after {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Select */
    .select-icon {
        width: 71px;
        height: 58px;
        background-color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        right: 1px;
        top: 1px;
        z-index: 10;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .select-icon img{
        width: 36px;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    /* Footer */
    footer {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100px;
        padding: 23px 0;
    }
    footer p {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #a6a6a6;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    li {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #fff;
    }
    li a,
    li a:hover,
    li a:visited,
    li a:focus,
    li a:active {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: SamsungOne;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .inner-container-footer {
        max-width: 960px;
    }
    .footer-image {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: 125px;
    }
    /* Datepicker */
    .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select {
        font-size: 12px !important;
        height: 30px;
        border-color: #c5c5c5;
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
    /* Helper classes */
    .no-pad {
        padding: 0;
    }
    .no-pad-left {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    .img-fluid {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .label-top {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .label-left {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
    .full-width {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .center {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .left {
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .right {
        margin-left: auto;
     }
    .flex-center {
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .flex-left{
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .flex-right {
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    /* Fonts */
    @font-face {
        font-family: SamsungOne;
        src: url('https://cdn.samsung.com/etc/designs/smg/global/fonts/SamsungOne-400.woff') format('woff');
        src: url('https://cdn.samsung.com/etc/designs/smg/global/fonts/SamsungOne-400.woff2') format('woff2');
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: SamsungSharpSansBd;
        src: url('https://cdn.samsung.com/etc/designs/smg/global/fonts/SamsungSharpSansBd.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    /* Mobile Styles */
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .readmore {
            height: 57px;
        }
        a.readmoreBtn {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        .label-left {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .label-left .form-elm-headline {
            align-self: flex-start;
        }
        .label-left .form-elm-rc {
            align-self: flex-start;
        }
        label.custom-input-container {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        input[type=text],
        select {
            height: 40px;
            padding: 0 15px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .select-icon {
            height: 38px;
            width: 45px;
        }
        .select-icon img {
            width: 22px;
        }
        .form-elm-wrapper {
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
        label.form-elm-headline {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        .form-elm-rc label {
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 30px;
        }
        .main-container {
            margin: 30px auto 35px auto;
        }
         h3 {
            font-size: 26px;
        }
        h4 {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        p {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        .parsley-errors {
            font-size: 10px;
            bottom: -15px;
        }
        .text-wrapper {
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
        li a,
        li a:hover,
        li a:visited,
        li a:focus,
        li a:active {
            font-size: 12px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        footer p {
            font-size: 10px;
        }
        .styled-btn {
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 18px;
            padding: 0 50px;
            height: 55px;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .btn-container .btn {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
        .hide-select-icon {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 374px) {
        .g-recaptcha {
            transform: scale(0.9);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
            transform-origin: 0 0;
            -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        }
        #facebook-btn {
            padding: 0 20px;
        }
    }
<!-- Start: Added for 5 star rating -->
#Q1 .rating {
  font-size: 0;
}
#Q1 .rating:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

#Q1 .rating input {
  display: none;
}
#Q1 .rating-label {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#Q1 .rating[dir="rtl"] {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
#Q1 .rating[dir="rtl"] > input:checked ~ .rating-label {
  font-size: 0;
}
#Q1 .rating[dir="rtl"] > input:checked ~ .rating-label:before {
  content: "\2605";
  color: #feca02;
}

#Q1 .rating-label.is-active {
  color: #feca02;
}


#Q1 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(1):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #02fe28;
}

#Q1 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(3):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #02fe28;
}

#Q1 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(5):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #02fe28;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(7):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #feca02;
}

#Q1 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(9):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #feca02;
}
}

#Q1 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(1):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #02fe28;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(3):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #02fe28;
}

#Q1 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(5):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #02fe28;
}

#Q1 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(7):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #feca02;
}

#Q1 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(9):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #feca02;
}
#Q1 .rating-large .rating-label {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
#Q1 .rating-large .rating-label:before {
  font-size: 32px;
}
#Q1 .rating-small .rating-label {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
#Q1 .rating-small .rating-label:before {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#Q1 .rating {
  margin: 15px auto;
}

#Q2 .rating {
  font-size: 0;
}
#Q2 .rating:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

#Q2 .rating input {
  display: none;
}
#Q2 .rating-label {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#Q2 .rating[dir="rtl"] {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
#Q2 .rating[dir="rtl"] > input:checked ~ .rating-label {
  font-size: 0;
}
#Q2 .rating[dir="rtl"] > input:checked ~ .rating-label:before {
  content: "\2605";
  color: #feca02;
}

#Q2 .rating-label.is-active {
  color: #feca02;
}


#Q2 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(1):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #02fe28;
}

#Q2 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(3):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #02fe28;
}

#Q2 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(5):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #02fe28;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(7):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #feca02;
}

#Q2 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(9):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #feca02;
}
}

#Q2 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(1):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #02fe28;
}

.rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(3):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #02fe28;
}

#Q2 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(5):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #02fe28;
}

#Q2 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(7):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #feca02;
}

#Q2 .rating[dir="rtl"]>input:nth-child(9):checked~.rating-label:before {
  color: #feca02;
}
#Q2 .rating-large .rating-label {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
#Q2 .rating-large .rating-label:before {
  font-size: 32px;
}
#Q2 .rating-small .rating-label {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
#Q2 .rating-small .rating-label:before {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#Q2 .rating {
  margin: 15px auto;
}
.submit-btn {
        background-color:#1428a0;
        color:#ffffff;
<!-- End: Added for 5 star rating -->
</style>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body style="" class="">
<div class="container">
<div class="row" id="content"><!-- START BODY -->
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-8 main-container"><form name="datacapture_form" id="datacapture_form" action="" method="POST" data-abide="">
<div class="row">
<div id="errorMsg"></div>
<div class="col-12 text-wrapper">

<h3 style="text-align: center;">Thank you for taking up the Survey!</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 text-wrapper">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">1. How is the customer service?</h4>
</div>
<div id="Q1" style="text-align: center;">
<div class="rating rating-large" dir="rtl">
<input name="rate" id="51" type="radio" value="1" /><label class="rating-label" for="51">&#9734</label> 
<input name="rate" id="41" type="radio" value="2" /> <label class="rating-label" for="41">&#9734</label> 
<input name="rate" id="31" type="radio" value="3" /> <label class="rating-label" for="31">&#9734</label> 
<input name="rate" id="21" type="radio" value="4" /> <label class="rating-label" for="21">&#9734</label> 
<input name="rate" id="11" type="radio" value="5" /> <label class="rating-label" for="11">&#9734</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="col-12 text-wrapper">
    <h4 style="text-align:center">2. How is the turn-around-time?</h4>
</div>
<div id="Q2" style="text-align: center;">
<div class="rating rating-large" dir="rtl">
<input name="rate" id="52" type="radio" value="1" /><label class="rating-label" for="52">&#9734</label> 
<input name="rate" id="42" type="radio" value="2" /> <label class="rating-label" for="42">&#9734</label> 
<input name="rate" id="32" type="radio" value="3" /> <label class="rating-label" for="32">&#9734</label> 
<input name="rate" id="22" type="radio" value="4" /> <label class="rating-label" for="22">&#9734</label> 
<input name="rate" id="12" type="radio" value="5" /> <label class="rating-label" for="12">&#9734</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="col-12">
<div class="submit-container"><button class="styled-btn submit-btn" id="submitform" type="submit" >SUBMIT</button></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All of your inputs have the same `name` attribute so they will behave like a single group. Give the inputs for each question a unique name.

Comment: Too much irrelevant code

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be completely sure without running the code, but I see that you have given both of your star sets the same `name` - so you technically have one set of radio buttons with two options for each of your values (two 1s, two 2s, etc). If each of these questions are independent of each other you should give them distinct names: one name for the first five, and one name for the second five.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example

```js
var inputsForm = document.querySelector("#inputs");
inputsForm.onchange = function(e) {
  if(e.target.type = "radio") {
    var stars = document.querySelectorAll(`[name='${e.target.name}']`);
    for(var i = 0;i < stars.length; i++) {
      if(i < e.target.value) {
        stars[i].parentElement.classList.replace("empty", "green");
      }else {
        stars[i].parentElement.classList.replace("green", "empty");
      }
    }
  }
}

// just for showing the values (not required only for testing)
inputsForm.onsubmit = function() {
  console.log(`How is the customer service? => ${this.question1.value}\nHow is the turn-around-time? => ${this.question2.value}`);
  return false;
}
```

```css
[name^='question'] {
  display: none;
}
.star {
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.empty i {
  color: #ccc;
}
.green i {
  color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<form id="inputs">
  <h2>Thank you for taking up the Survey!</h2>
  <h3>How is the customer service?</h3>
  <label class="star green"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="1"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
  <label class="star green"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="2"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
  <label class="star green"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="3" checked><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
  <label class="star empty"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="4"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
  <label class="star empty"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="5"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
  <h3>How is the turn-around-time?</h3>
  <label class="star green"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="1"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
  <label class="star green"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="2"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
  <label class="star green"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="3" checked><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
  <label class="star empty"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="4"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
  <label class="star empty"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="5"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```